# cURL and etag usage?

Tags: curl, http-headers

how would I send an etag over cURL? also can cURL save the etag like it does with COOKIEJAR?

from the headers i see this

my GET request

```
GET /Vpreviews/p/8b329b598fcdad4fd33432e78128da48f7219882.fll?    e=1332973900&ri=4500&rs=75&h=bca0ce28998e637f27cf1d5c7042e7a0 HTTP/1.1
Host: veoh-139.vo.llnwd.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

server response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Veoh-1.5 (lighttpd-1.4.18)
Content-Type: video/x-flv
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Etag: "8b329b598fcdad4fd33432e78128da48f72198829640882"
User-Header: X-llnw-rate-limit: ri=4500, rs=98
Age: 162476
Date: Wed, 28 Mar 2012 22:06:41 GMT
Last-Modified: Sun, 01 Jan 2012 13:29:44 GMT
Expires: Mon, 27 Mar 2017 06:02:35 GMT
Content-Length: 9640882
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: FYI: Recent curl versions have built-in ETag support https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2019/12/06/curl-speaks-etag/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Take a look at this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/321-http-caching).  In the show notes, you can see examples of using curl to grab a page with cookies and ETags.

Basically, you pass it in with a 'If-None-Match' header:

```
curl -I http://localhost:3000/books/1 --header 'If-None-Match: "0f46357eafa5c719e8e3bf277a993e07"'
```

Comment: The link provided above does not display show notes unless you purchase a subscription to their podcast.

Comment: On my case the error was not enclosing the etag hash between quotes. This example helped me to point that out.

Answer (score 14):

First of all, Curl is just a utility for performing http requests. It doesn't automatically record response headers such as the Cookie or the ETag header.

But you can, for instance, write the headers to a file using the `--dump-header` option and extract the sought after header from the dump file and us it in the next request.

```
curl --dump-header header_dump www.google.no
```

As for sending the ETag, I'm guessing that you want to perform a conditional GET request. That is, you want to instruct the server (or in fact the application) that you're only interested in a 200 OK response if the resource has been modified since the last request.

If that is what you're after, you can achieve this by adding the If-None-Match: header to the request:

```
 curl -I -v --header 'If-None-Match: "1d30-4c993ec28581d"' http://httpd.apache.org
```

Note how the header above is wrapped in single quotes while the Etag value is wrapped in double quotes. It won't work unless you do that.

If the Etag matches, you should get a 304 response like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Tue, 18 Sep 2012 11:02:17 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.1 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.0g
ETag: "1d30-4c993ec28581d"
```

Comment: Regarding the double quotes: ETag values must be passed back to the server _exactly_ as given by the server. Do not add or remove quotes. In your example the server gave an ETag with quotes, so that's exactly what needs to be passed back to If-None-Match, which you can do like this: `curl -I -v --header "If-None-Match: $(sed 's/Etag: \(.*\)/\1/p;d' /path/to/header_dump)" http://httpd.apache.org`

Comment: One can use a more basic Sed expression (no capturing groups): `curl --header "If-None-Match: $(sed -n '/^Etag: */{ s///; p ;}' /path/to/header_dump)" ...`

Comment: Headers use CRLF (\r\n) as line break, so the sed command must take that into account, this is what I use: `sed -n 's/^ETag:\s*\(.*\)\r$/\1/p'` otherwise the CR is goint to be included in the ETag and is not going to match.

Answer (score 4):

Etags are just a Http request header just like any other from curls point of view.

So you can just use:

```
curl -v -H 'If-None-Match: 123456789' http:your.server.com/your/path/here
```

where *123456789* is the value of the Etag you got back from your first request.

Comment: This is only part of the answer. Etag can't be saved for later use as for cookies.

Comment: Thats true, but the original question had 2 parts to it, and that is the answer for the first part. I guess I should add that the answer to the second part "also can cURL save the etag like it does with COOKIEJAR?" is No.